# css transform and animation conflicting; order of html elements matters?

Tags: html, css, animation, transform

So, I have a menu that is rounded on the ends, and delineated by diagonal spaces (accomplished with css transform skewx). I also have a element that is animated with css animation.

The problem is this: if the animated element is placed before the menu in the DOM. the menu deforms until the animation is done. If I place the animated element after the menu in the DOM, it works fine.

I want to keep the animated element at the top of the DOM. How can I resolve this with css?

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jh23q93/5/)

Markup:

```
<div class="testanimation"></div>

<div class="testmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="one"><span><p>ONE</p></span></li>
        <li class="two"><span><p>TWO</p></span></li>
        <li class="three"><span><p>THREE</p></span></li>
        <li class="four"><span><p>FOUR</p></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And heres' the css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes cart-modified{
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    35% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
.testanimation{
    -webkit-animation: cart-modified 0.5s ease 2 0.25s;
    min-width: 1.25em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    background-color: #fa001f;
    background-color: rgba(250, 0, 31, 0.9);

}

.testmenu ul{
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 95%;
}
.testmenu ul li{
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
.testmenu span{
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
    display: block;
    color: white;
}
.one{
    padding-left: 40px !important;
    margin-left: -60px !important;
}
.four{
    padding-right: 40px !important;
    margin-right: -30px !important;
}
```

Thanks for your knowledge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weird bug, because I'm about 99% sure that CSS animations are supposed to be asynchronous. I'm able to fake it by including a `skewX(0)` property on the `ul` as well.

```
.testmenu ul{
    -webkit-transform: skewX(0);
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lgq205d/

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I thought they were asynchronous as well. But I couldn't figure out a way to force it to work. Thanks!